# JHipster edit blueprint

Tags: jhipster

Hi I am trying to use JHipster for .net (very first thing I noticed is that when I create entity, even thought I am being asked if I want to create separate service or use context directly in controller, I select separate service and it doesn't work, the context is used directly in controllers.

But this is my questions: is it possible to edit available blueprint or only by forking git repo and edit it for my need, but then loosing possibility to get updates for blueprint ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is not possible to edit blueprints without forking them. You can fork and extend the blueprint to customize stuff. But in this case, the best thing would be to open an issue in the JHipster .net blueprint GitHub repository  to report the issue and if possible do a PR to fix it so it helps wider community